# ajax request in codeigniter returning html code instead of redirecting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've added a constructor in a class to check if some user is logged in.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('encryption');
    if (!$this->session->userdata('id') || $this->session->userdata('role') != 'CUSTOMER') {
        redirect('account/login');
    }
}
```

Here's the ajax

```
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url("cart/addToCart"); ?>',
            dataType: 'text',
            data:{'id':val},
            success:function(data) {
              if (data != 'added') {
                alert('Opps! something went wrong, please try again');
              }
            }
        });
```

but if I try to call this request without session, it's not redirecting to login page but giving the whole login page code which I can see in [network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlgRP.png)

Comment: you can't do ajax redirection through the server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, Ajax simply return a response text. It will not proccess the request

You can try something like following

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url("cart/addToCart"); ?>',
            dataType: 'text',
            data:{'id':val, 'type':'ajax'}, //say this request coming from a ajax
            success:function(data) {
              if (data != 'added') {
                 if(data == "not_log_in"){ //checking whether login or not
                       window.location = "login_page";
                 }else{
                       alert('Opps! something went wrong, please try again');
                 }
              }
            }
        });
```

**Controller**

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('id') || $this->session->userdata('role') != 'CUSTOMER') {
       if(isset($_POST["type"])){ // checking whether request coming from ajax or not
           echo "not_log_in"; // if it is ajax, simply show an error massage
       }else{
            redirect('account/login'); //otherwise redirect
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `return` to your redirect:

```
return redirect('account/login');
```

Comment: @fraggely I've added return before redirect(), it's still not redirecting

Comment: are you sure you are getting through the if statement? Change the if statement to something that will 100% be true (or remove it completely) to test the redirect. If that works then the issue is your if statement

Comment: I've removed if statement in the constructor but it still not redirecting, I can't understand where I messed up

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises due to `ajax` request not being completed. When the redirection happens it continues to treat it as `ajax` request, hence it shows the new page in the network tab. 
To solve this you'll have to redirect it to any other function and send a response from it but as you are checking the session in `constructor`, we'll have to check a condition for that particular `function(method)`.

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'<?php echo base_url("cart/addToCart/some_new_function"); ?>',  // make a new function {some_new_function}
    dataType: 'json',  // expects json to be returned
    data:{'id':val},
    success:function(data) {
        if (data == 1) { // fail
            window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('account/login'); ?>"; // your-location-&-logic
        }else{
            // whatever-you-want-to-do
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('encryption');

    $method = $this->router->fetch_method(); // get method name

    if($method !== 'some_new_function'){     
        if (!$this->session->userdata('id') || $this->session->userdata('role') != 'CUSTOMER') {
            redirect('account/login');
        }
    }
}

function some_new_function(){  // control will come here from ajax after construct
    //perform session check here
     if (!$this->session->userdata('id') || $this->session->userdata('role') != 'CUSTOMER') {
        echo 0; // fail
    }else{
        echo 1; // success // perform-your-task-here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.